# Python 3 dataclass initialization

Tags: python, python-3.x

Do dataclasses have a way to add additional initialization aside from what is provided with its built in initializer, without overriding it? Specifically, I want to check some values of a list of integers that is one of the fields in the data class upon initialization.

Comment: Did you read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#post-init-processing?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

As described in the [dataclass PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#post-init-processing), there is a `__post_init__` method, which will be the last thing called by `__init__`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class DataClass: 
    some_field: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        print(f"My field is {self.some_field}")
```

Defining this dataclass class, and then running the following:

```
dc = DataClass(1) # Prints "My field is 1"
```

Would initialize `some_field` to 1, and then run `__post_init__`, printing `My field is 1`.

This allows you to run code after the initialization method to do any additional setup/checks you might want to perform.

Comment: Just as a warning, if you use 
```from attr import dataclass```, this would not work!

Comment: Thanks! I tried to redefine `__init__` and wondered why it is not called and any breakpoints aren't helping :)