# Dataclass and Callable Initialization Problem via Classmethods

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, callable, python-dataclasses

I found this weird behaviour where I don't know if I am the problem or if this is a python / dataclass / callable bug.

Here is a minimal working example

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Callable
import numpy as np


def my_dummy_callable(my_array, my_bool):
    return 1.0


@dataclass()
class MyDataClassDummy:

    my_data: int = 1
    my_callable: Callable[[np.ndarray, bool], float] = my_dummy_callable

    def __init__(self):
        print("I initialized my Class!")

    @classmethod
    def my_factory_with_callable_setting(cls):
        my_dummy = MyDataClassDummy()
        my_dummy.my_callable = my_dummy_callable
        return my_dummy

    @classmethod
    def my_factory_without_callable_setting(cls):
        my_dummy = MyDataClassDummy()
        return my_dummy

    def do_something(self):
        print("This is my data", self.my_data)
        print("This is the name of my callable", str(self.my_callable))
        return self.my_callable(np.empty(shape=(42, 42)), True) + self.my_data


@dataclass()
class MySecondDataClassDummy:
    my_data: int = 4
    my_callable: Callable[[np.ndarray, bool], float] = my_dummy_callable

    @classmethod
    def my_factory(cls):
        my_dummy = MySecondDataClassDummy()
        return my_dummy

    def do_something(self):
        print("This is my data", self.my_data)
        print("This is the name of my callable", str(self.my_callable))
        return self.my_callable(np.empty(shape=(42, 42)), True) - self.my_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # this works
    my_first_dummy = MyDataClassDummy.my_factory_with_callable_setting()
    my_first_dummy.do_something()

    # this also works
    my_second_dummy = MySecondDataClassDummy.my_factory()
    my_second_dummy.do_something()

    # this does not work
    my_other_dummy = MyDataClassDummy.my_factory_without_callable_setting()
    my_other_dummy.do_something()
```

case1: initialize with factory, initialize with my own init and then set the callable explicitly after initialization (allthough there is a default value) - works

case2: initialize with factory but don't explicitly code the init() myself - works

case3: initialize with factory, initialize with my own init and not set the callable explicitly after initialization (because this is why I have default values, isn't it?!) - doesn't work but throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_path/dataclass_dummy.py", line 63, in <module>
    my_other_dummy.do_something()
  File "my_path/dataclass_dummy.py", line 33, in do_something
    return self.my_callable(np.empty(shape=(42, 42)), True) + self.my_data
TypeError: my_dummy_callable() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

So now I am wondering, what I am doing wrong in the third case.

I am using Python 3.8 and numpy 1.20.2

Comment: It's just `@dataclass` and not `@dataclass()` if no arguments are passed to the decorator, as in your case you are not passing any arguments to it. It looks nicer without the parentheses. Just saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@dataclass` decorator by default supplies an `__init__()` method to a class. This method turns type annotated class variables into attributes of instances of the class. This mechanism is used in the case of the class `MySecondDataClassDummy`. In effect, every instance of this class has an attribute `my_callable`. Since this attribute is a function, you can call it as you do in Case 2, and everything works.

The class `MyDataClassDummy` has its own `__init__()` method, which overrides  `__init__()` provided by `@dataclass`. Instances of this class are then initialized more or less as they would be without the `@dataclass` decorator. In particular, class variables that are functions become bound methods of class instances. As a result, `my_callable` becomes such a bound method, and when in Case 3 you execute

```
self.my_callable(np.empty(shape=(42, 42)), True)
```

then `self` is used as the first argument of `my_callable`. Since this function takes only two arguments, it generates an error.

The same problem does not occur in Case 1, since in this case you modify
`my_dummy.my_callable` making it an attribute of `my_dummy` whose value is a function. After this modification, it is not a bound method anymore.

Comment: That makes sense and is somehow what I thought I would be missing, thanks!. So If I implement the `__post_init__` function instead of the `__init__` function in MyDataClassDummy to add my own initialization Code, then all three cases work. (I found the `__post_init__` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199031/python-3-dataclass-initialization))